# How to access variables in pyomo objective rule function

Tags: variables, pyomo, maximize

I'm new to pyomo.  I'm trying to find a set of variable values that will maximize the result of a function I specify as the rule in a pyomo Objective object.  Here is a simplified version of what I'm trying.  The tryIt function is just a simple test.  The actual function is complex and can't be expressed as a simple expression.

What I was hoping for is that the solver would call the tryIt function with all variations of the 2 variables and identify the set that caused tryIt to return the maximum value.  However, it is called just once with the initialized values.  I can imagine I need to specify a set of values to use, but I have not found how to do that. I thought the solver might try all integers within the specified bounds.

I just found in another post, "Remember that the objective function rule is not a call-back function that is evaluated multiple times by the solver. The objective function rule should return an algebraic expression involving Pyomo variables".  Well, I doubt I can do that.

Is there a tool/solver that will do a callback passing the model?

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.environ import *

def tryIt(model):
    print(model.v1.value, model.v2.value)
    return model.v1.value * 2 + model.v2.value * 3

model = ConcreteModel()

model.v1 = Var(within=pyo.PositiveIntegers, bounds=(1,2), initialize = 1)
model.v2 = Var(within=pyo.PositiveIntegers, bounds=(3,4), initialize = 3)

model.objective = Objective(rule = tryIt, sense = maximize)

results = SolverFactory('glpk').solve(model, tee = True)

model.pprint()
```

Comment: the code you posted runs & solves properly.  Perhaps some conceptual issues with what pyomo & solver are doing here and what other options might work for you.  If you have some arbitrarily complicated function of some set of variables, you might want to look at `scipy.optimize`.  The use of pyomo + solver would probably work too, but it is tough to say without more info.  pyomo + solver works best on linear probs with many variables, or indexed variables, etc.

Comment: Note:  pyomo "calls" the function only with the intent to retrieve the expression that is returned.  That expression, along with all the other pieces of the model, are packaged and sent to the solver, which may evaluate that expression arbitrarily often.  If the rule function is indexed by a set, it is called once for each set member

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  pyomo won't work as it does not actually call the objective function and my function can't return a simple expression.  I tried SciPy, and at least with the solvers I tried, it tries tiny variations in parameters seeking a derivative which results in identical values from my function, and the conclusion it has found the minimum.